# Mocha-Express unit test fails with localhost as URL

Tags: testing, express, localhost, server, mocha.js

I have written the following script (server.js):

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server;

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.send('This is the main page.\n');});

exports.listen = function (port){
    server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server available listening at: ' + port);}) };

exports.close = function () {
  server.close(function (){
    console.log('Server Closed')}); };
```

and the following Mocha unit test (test.js):

```
var server = require ('./server'),
    assert = require ('assert'),
    http = require ('http');
var port = 8085;

describe('server', function () {
  before(function () {
    server.listen(port)});

  after(function () {
    server.close();}); });

describe('Server status and Message', function () {
  it('status response should be equal 200', function (done) {
    http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8085', function (response) {
         assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
        done(); }); }); });
```

When I run the test.js passing either 'localhost:8085' or '127.0.0.1:8085' to http client, with whatever port, Mocha show the following error:

```
1) Server status and Message status response should be equal 200:
     Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
      at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

But I can connect the server perfectly via http client wiht the same localhost url (listener.js):

```
var server = require('./server');
var http = require('http');

    var url = 'http://localhost:8085';
    var content = function(response){
        response.setEncoding("utf8");       
        response.on("data", function(data) {
                console.log(data)});}

    server.listen(8085);
    setTimeout(function (){server.close();}, 3000)

    http.get(url, content);
```

I have tried running the unit test with others internet url's as 'https://www.google.com.co/' (the test doesn't pass but works) and the test runs correctly.

Could you help me with this issue. Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accidentally running two sets of tests.  Move the second describe() inside the first one so it can rely on the before() hook, like this:

```
var server = require ('./server'),
    assert = require ('assert'),
    http = require ('http');
var port = 8085;

describe('server', function () {
    before(function () {
        server.listen(port);
    });

    after(function () {
        server.close();
    });

    describe('Server status and Message', function () {
      it('status response should be equal 200', function (done) {
            http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8085', function (response) {
                  assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
                  done();
            });
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked! But I remember th original code (as my question) worked some time. I take it from [here](http://taylor.fausak.me/2013/02/17/testing-a-node-js-http-server-with-mocha/). I'd like to know why now, with your suggestion, it works, and, it's correct having a describe into other describe? Thank you very much!

Comment: It likely worked sometimes due to a race condition (that is, the server was able to start up before the tests ran, which is not guaranteed to happen in the code you posted).  By using before(), we guarantee that the server will start first. describe() is simply a way to group your tests together, so it is perfectly acceptable to next them as you see fit.